# I can't hide my EAGLView object for accessibility tools

Tags: objective-c, accessibility, cocos2d-x, eaglview

I created a cocos2d-x project and there is a class called `AppController.mm` where an EAGLView object (`__glView`) is created. The accessibility of `__glView` is set to true/yes by default but I want it to be false/no so I can access my elements which are behind the EAGLView with an automation tool like UI Automation Tool by Xcode. Now when I try to set the accessibility of that view to false, I use that line of code in `AppController.mm` after it's created:

```
[__glView setIsAccessibilityElement:NO];
```

But this setter doesn't do anything. It ignores that and is still true/yes. In a test project, I override the getter in `EAGLView.mm` like this:

```
- (BOOL) isAccessibilityElement
{
    return NO;
}
```

and it works perfectly fine. The problem in my real project is, that I don't have access to `EAGLView.mm` so I thought using the setter would be nice but it doesn't do anything.

If I use

`[__glView setAccessibilityElementsHidden:YES]`

then it works (doesn't ignore it) but of course everything is hidden, so I can't even have access to my own elements which are under EAGLView. I just want to hide this specific `__glView`.

Comment: Have you checked that __glView is non-nil when you send the setIsAccessibilityElement message? Btw often setters for BOOL properties beginning with "is" aren't named setIs.. but simply setAccessibilityElement. You might want to try that, or simply use dot notation: __glView.isAccessibilityElement = NO; or __glView.accessibilityElement = NO; whichever works.

Comment: Thanks but it is with setIs.. it even gets suggested, there is no `setAccessibilityElement` only `setAccessibilityElementsHidden`. And i tried with the dot notation, still the same problem, it gets ignored so it is still `YES`.

Comment: And is __glView non-nil at that point where you try to change accessibility? If it's nil, Objective-C will ignore the message rather than crashing as C/C++ would when dereferencing a NULL pointer.

Comment: `__glView` is not nil, but thanks for helping.